# Looking for Primos "name generation" code

Tags: shell

Does anyone remember Primos? It had a shell-level thing called ***name generation*** which was very useful. For example, to rename a bunch of files from ***part1.suffix*** to ***part1.new.suffix2*** you could say:

```
rename *.suffix =.+new.suffix2
```

That's a very simple example, it was quite powerful. The control characters were:

```
=,==,^=,^==,+
```

Which meant approximately: match 1 filename component, match all remaining components, delete one component, delete all remaining, add a component.

In conjunction with Primos wildcards you could do pretty much any useful file renaming/copying operation very conveniently.

It was much better than Unix wildcards and name generation/iteration and I'd like to find it again and use it. Has anyone seen it around?

Comment: Might be better on superuser...

Comment: also look into zsh, it has some pretty powerful globbing and renaming capabilities. http://www.rayninfo.co.uk/tips/zshtips.html

Comment: Thanks for zsh tips. Will check those. Looks like Primos has pretty much vanished. Cripes, I spent all the 80's on Primos. Greg E